# Clarification on heaps - do they have to be filled to be a valid heap?

Tags: heap

Aka

```
     1
2          3
```

Is a valid heap?

Whereas

```
    1
2
```

Is not, as the tree is not filled up on all levels?

Or does the structure property of heaps only specify that the heap is just filled out such that there is no "gap" between elements in level order. Meaning that the second heap is  a valid heap as well?

Or does the structure property for heaps just require that the heap is FULL, aka every parent has 0 or two chidren?

So

```
           1
       2      3  
   4     7   9   99
```

Is a valid heap, as is

```
           1
       2      3  
   4     7
```

BUT NOT

```
          1
       2      3  
   4     7   9
```

?

Comment: you are using the term "heap" in a way that is confusing to me...

Comment: I'm referring to the data structure and am modeling it using a tree representation more or less stolen from what I can scavenge from wikipedia - they have such a representation here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: Ah - this is likely the source of confusion: "A heap data structure should not be confused with the heap which is a common name for the pool of memory from which dynamically allocated memory is allocated. The term was originally used only for the data structure."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a question on terminology. However, almost always a heap is defined as a rooted tree, where:

1. for every node except root its key is not less than the key of its parent
2. every node has 0, 1 or 2 children and
3. the tree is almost a  complete binary tree but for, possibly, the last level. The last level should be filled from left to right.

So, these are valid heaps:

```
        1                5
     2     3          9     8
   3  6   9         11
```

And these are not:

```
        1                5
     2                9     8
   3                   13  9 10
```